# 25 / 100 = 0, Почему?

Tags: c#, c++, c

Мне нужно по некой формуле высчитать результат, но это не удается потому что в ней используется деление числа 25 на число 100.
Все это выглядит примерно так:

```
double i = 25 / 100; // В этом случае будет выводиться 0, а мне нужно 0.25
```

В чём здесь проблема?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

У Вас в действии `int`-операнд **25** делится на `int`-операнд **100**. Соответственно и деление происходит целочисленное. Для ожидаемого Вами результата необходимо хотя бы один из операндов привести к типу `double`. Например:

```
double i = 25 / 100d;
```

Answer (score 4):

потому что это инт.

```
double i = 25.0 / 100;
```

либо приведите (cast) к double, наверное это делается так:

```
double i = (double)25 / 100;
```

Answer (score 2):

Измени свой код на:

```
double i = 25 / 100d;
```

Иначе компилятор считает, что выполняется целочисленное деление, которое в данном случае вернет 0 вместо 0.25.