# Массив объектов класса дробь сортируется некорректно

Tags: c++, сортировка, пузырьковая-сортировка

Создал класс - дробь, сделал массив, передал его в функцию сортировки пузырьком (нужно именно этим методом). После сортировки, неясно откуда, выводятся числа, которых не было изначально. Проходил дебаггером, проблема где-то в функции. Имя функции - sort

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

#define N 10

class Fraction
{

private:
    int chys,
        zn;
public:
    Fraction()
    {
        this->chys = 0;
        this->zn = 0;
    }

    Fraction(int chys, int zn)
    {
        this->chys = chys;
        this->zn = zn;
    }

    Fraction(const Fraction &obj)
    {
        this->chys = obj.chys;
        this->zn = obj.zn;
    }

    int GetChys() { return chys; }
    int GetZn() { return zn; }
    void setFraction(int x, int y) { chys = x; zn = y; }

    int CommonZn(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        int q = 0;
        int i = 0;

        for (i = 1; q != 1; i++)
        {
            if ((i % A->zn == 0) && (i % B->zn == 0))
            {
                q = 1;
                A->chys *= (i / A->zn);
                B->chys *= (i / B->zn);
            }
        }
        A->zn = i - 1;
        B->zn = i - 1;
        this->zn = i - 1;
        return i - 1;
    }

    int skor(int *chys, int *zn)
    {
        int i = 0, b = 0;
        if (*chys > *zn) { b = *chys; }
        else (b = *zn);
        for (i = b; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (*chys%i == 0 && *zn%i == 0)
            {
                *chys = *chys / i;
                *zn = *zn / i;
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

    void comperizon(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        if (A->chys > B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Перший дріб більший за другий" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys == B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Дроби однакові" << endl; }
        else if (A->chys < B->chys) { cout << endl; cout << "Другий дріб більший за перший" << endl; }
    }

    void addition(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys + B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nСума дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void subtraction(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = A->chys - B->chys;
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nРізниця дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void multiplication(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->chys);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->zn);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nДобуток дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    void division(Fraction *A, Fraction *B)
    {
        this->chys = (A->chys * B->zn);
        this->zn = (A->zn * B->chys);
        skor(&this->chys, &this->zn);
        cout << "\nЧастка дробів = ";
        cout << *this;
        cout << endl;
    }

    Fraction const& operator=(Fraction &second)
    {
        chys = second.chys; zn = second.zn;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator == (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        return (this->chys == obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator >= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        return (this->chys >= obj.chys);
    }

    bool operator > (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        return (this->chys / this->zn > obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator < (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        return (this->chys / this->zn < obj.chys / obj.zn);
    }

    bool operator <= (const Fraction &obj)
    {
        return (this->chys <= obj.chys);
    }

    friend Fraction& operator +(const Fraction &first, const Fraction &second)
    {
        return *new Fraction(first.chys + second.chys, first.zn);
    }

    friend istream &operator >> (istream &in, Fraction &fraction) {
        in >> fraction.chys;
        in.ignore(1);
        in >> fraction.zn;
        return in;
    }

    friend ostream &operator << (ostream &out, const Fraction &fr)
    {
        out << fr.chys << "/" << fr.zn;
        return out;
    }

    void sort(Fraction *FrArray)
    {
        Fraction changer;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
            {
                if (FrArray[i] > FrArray[j])
                {
                    changer = FrArray[i];
                    FrArray[i] = FrArray[j];
                    FrArray[j] = changer;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ~Fraction() { }
};


int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    system("color f0");
    system("cls");
    int chys1, zn1, chys2, zn2;
    srand(time(nullptr));

    Fraction FrArray[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) 
    {
        FrArray[i].setFraction(1 + rand() % 10, 1 + rand() % 10);
        cout << i+1 << "й елемент масиву = " << FrArray[i] << endl;
    }

    FrArray->sort(FrArray);

    cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        FrArray[i].setFraction(1 + rand() % 10, 1 + rand() % 10);
        cout << i + 1 << "й елемент масиву = " << FrArray[i] << endl;
    }

    Fraction *A = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nПерший дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *A;

    Fraction *B = new Fraction();
    cout << "\nДругий дріб = " << endl;
    cin >> *B;

    Fraction *C = new Fraction(*A);

    C->CommonZn(A, B);
    C->comperizon(A, B);
    C->addition(A, B);
    C->subtraction(A, B);
    C->multiplication(A, B);
    C->division(A, B);
    cout << endl;

    *C = *A + *B;
    //cout << *C;
    cout << endl;

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Только что попробовал сделать 2 переменных вместо одного объекта, для отдельного присваивания внутри функции, для числителя и знаменателя, результат тот же.

Comment: Операторы >=, <= и == определены неправильно

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, что подметили, но проблема точно не в них)

Comment: Операторы `<` и `>` тоже определены неправильно. Также не ясно зачем `sort` сделано методом класса.

Comment: @AnT как мне следует их определить? Не могу понять

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/86969/25-100-0-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема у вас в том, что в коде вы отсортированный массив заполняете новыми значениями, вместо вывода существующих

```
cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        FrArray[i].setFraction(1 + rand() % 10, 1 + rand() % 10);
        cout << i + 1 << "й елемент масиву = " << FrArray[i] << endl;
    }
```

Правильный вариант:

```
cout << "Sorted: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cout << i + 1 << "й елемент масиву = " << FrArray[i] << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Ох... Не заметил. Большое спасибо

Comment: Еще проблема - первый елемент на своем месте всегда остается.. Не знаете, что может быть?

Comment: @GetRight Пока не представляю из-за чего, пройдитесь отладчиком по всем этапам сортировки, попробуйте несколько раз, возможно тогда поймёте в чём суть проблемы